# How do I convert this lazy assignment via ajax into a promise?

Tags: javascript, jquery, promise, when-js

I looked at [this question about caching](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15432444/335847) and [this one about conditional promises](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19099522/335847) but to be honest, I'm still a bit confused, as I've never used promises before.

I'm using [when.js v2.5.1](https://github.com/cujojs/when/tree/2.5.1) and jQuery v2.0.3. I'm trying to convert the following code into a promise (it's so much clearer in coffeescript so I'll stick with that, but feel free to respond with javascript)

```
class Loader
  @files: {}
  @load: (path) ->
    @files[path] ?= $.ajax(url: path).responseText
```

to be called like this:

```
mytext = Loader.load "/path/to/greatness"
```

So, I know I want to return a promise. I know jQuery's xhr is a deferrable and implements the Promise API Something, so could I do something like this?

```
class Loader
  @files: {}
  @load: (path) ->
    if @files[path]
      deferred = When.defer()
      deferred.resolve @files[path]
      deferred.promise
    else
      $.ajax(url: path).done (data)=>
        @files[path] = xhr.responseText
```

because whatever gets returned can have `then` called on it…?

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are  firing off multiple requests for the same file because the if test gives false until the request completes. You should immediately
assign it so only one request for a file is ever made

The resolution value of successfull ajax should a meaningful reflection of the responseText anyway so you can just do this:

```
class Loader
  @files: {}
  @load: (path) ->
    if not @files[path]
      @files[path] = $.ajax(url: path)
    @files[path]
```

Comment: Thanks, I was overthinking it.